# If $f$ is unbounded, then is $f$ infinite?

Tags: analysis

How can this not be?

If $n$ is in the image of $f$, then $n+1$ must be in the image of $f$, right? so this tends to infinity?

Comment: What is $f$? What does it mean for $f$ to be infinite?

Comment: Actually I meant- is a finite function bounded?

Comment: What is a finite function?

Comment: $f<\infty$ for all x in domain

Comment: $f$ is a function not a number. I assume you mean $f(x) < \infty$ for every $x$, but that is true of every function.

Comment: What do you mean by '$f$ is infinite'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the map $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$. Is this a finite function? Is it bounded?

Answer (score 2):

A function can be unbounded without having a limit of infinity. For example a function which oscillates with increasing amplitude.